# create patch file with "git diff" command to patching multiple files

Tags: git, patch

I need to patching several files. I use the patch file to modify linux kernel devicetree files. These files are not part of a git repository but they are simple text files stored in a folder on my PC.

To patch a single file I use the following command

```
git diff --no-index my_file_original.txt my_file_modified.txt > ./my_file.patch
```

First question. Are the SHA (Secure Hash Algorithm) codes contained in the patch file, essential? Let me explain better. Once the patch file is made, if I edit it with a text editor by adding or removing parts, I suppose the SHA codes don't match with the new file content, is it right? Under these conditions, does the patch file still work correctly when it is used in the build process of the linux kernel?

Second question. Let suppose now to have for example four files named `my_file1_original.txt, my_file2_original.txt, my_file3_original.txt, my_file4_original.txt`.

What is the way to create with "git diff" ONE ONLY `my_file.patch` file that compare and patches the couples :

```
my_file1_original.txt / my_file1_modified.txt
my_file2_original.txt / my_file2_modified.txt
my_file3_original.txt / my_file3_modified.txt
my_file4_original.txt / my_file4_modified.txt
```

Many thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use `git diff` between two commits, or between a commit and the worktree :

- create a first commit with the initial content for the 4 files (or, since you talk about the linux kernel, start from the commit you expect on the linux kernel)
- update said files to the content you want
- run `git diff` (no arguments) : you should have a patch that describes how to update the 4 files

if you have other modified files, you can restrict the scope of `git diff` by naming the files you want after a `--` :

```
git diff -- my_file1 my_file2 my_file3 my_file4
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Now all is clear.